# Two textures one output

Tags: texturing, materials

I try to use two texture in the same material.This material is for a jacket, and one texture containing the default leather material texture, and the other someting like a decorative stripes. My question is, how to blend the two textures together in the same output. I tried the "Mix" node with not too much success.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to mix them together with a *Color* > *MixRGB* node and find the right mode (here *Multiply*). Don't forget to put a *Diffuse* node after the *MixRGB*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using the textures for one shader so:

Use a mask by painting (or placing) a black and white texture in factor socket mix rgb node.

- if the details texture are on a transparent png, use the alpha output of the png image as your mask and connect the alpha to factor of mix rgb. if it shows wrong try inverting the mask color or swapping the color1 with color2.

[image]